# When i click on popup button it opened google providers and i clicked on close button, immediately i click on login button popup not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In React App, when I click on login button, it opened popup window and I closed it. Again immediately I clicked on login button, the popup google provider not opened.

step by step action:
Step 1) refresh the app
step 2) click on login button, it display google providers.
step 3) click on close button on popup google provider login, it closed the popup.
step 4) again click on login button, google provider login popup not displayed.
step 5) refresh the url, click on login button. it displayed google provider popup.

Here is my logic.
Login menu.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Navbar, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { startLogout } from '../../actions/auth';
import {SignInScreen} from '../../firebase/firebase';
import { history } from '../../routers/AppRouter';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class NavbarPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    state = {
        clicked: false,
        login: false
    }
    Authorization = event => {
        console.log('clicked: ', history.location.pathname)
        {history.location.pathname==='/' ? 
        this.setState({ login: true }) :
        this.props.startLogout()}
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState ({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className="Navbar-bg" expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/">Money Manage</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="ml-5">
                            {history.location.pathname==='/' ? 
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link> : 
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/dashboard">dashboard</Nav.Link>} 
                            {history.location.pathname==='/dashboard' && <Nav.Link  as={Link} to="/create">add</Nav.Link>}
                            <Nav.Link>
                                <button className="signupBtn active" onClick={this.Authorization}> 
                                    {history.location.pathname==='/' ? 'Login' : 'Logout'} 
                                </button>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                {this.state.login && 
                  <SignInScreen />
                }
                {history.location.pathname==='/' && 
                  <div className="Nav-header">
                    <h3 className="font-weight-bold">Money Management Application</h3>
                    <p className="text-indent"> It is used to the people who do regular money exchange and no need to save in any local desktop or mobile or physical notepad. It is user friendly for the people who regularly doing money transactions like giving or borrowing money</p>
                  </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    startLogin: (provider) => dispatch(startLogin(provider)),
    startLogout: () => dispatch(startLogout())
 })

 export default connect(undefined,mapDispatchToProps)(NavbarPage);
```

firebase/google provider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const database = firebase.database();
 
export class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        show: true
    }
    
    
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState ({show: false})
  }

  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          dialogClassName="modal-50w"
      >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Login using below account</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}/>
          </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export { firebase, database as default };
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was when i click on Login second time, in firebase.js component default state show = true was not changing to true, it is showing as false. I fixed it by moving login button and its onclick functonality to firebase.js component then it worked.